# Modify print job's Owner property (Not Delete Print Job)

Tags: c#, printing

I want to change print owner of print in print job property.
(Print Owner : Display in What's printing dialogue box.)

I tried to modify it by SetJob function but unable to change, setjob return's error.

Try 1 : `SetJob(hPrinter, nJobId, 1, (LPBYTE)pJobInfo1, 0);`

Try 2 : `SetJob(hPrinter, nJobId, 2, (LPBYTE)pJobInfo2, 0);`

Try 3 : `SetJob(hPrinter, nJobId, 4, (LPBYTE)pJobInfo4, 0);`

One more thing job is already register in print queue, which i can not remove, I need to modify it only.

More detail : I am at betwwen EnumPorts & StartDocPort events.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

To set Print owner.
Before calling setjob function, need to set set 
pJobInfo->Position = JOB_POSITION_UNSPECIFIED;

It works for me.